# rPi4 no longer capable of HDMI output. Eeprom recovery did not help

Tags: hardware, hdmi, troubleshooting, recovery

I have a rPi 4 that died on me, in two stages:

- First it would only show a yellow screen on HDMI outputs.
- Then later, it completely stopped outputting HDMI altogether. It seems to be in a reboot loop?

Things I have tried:

- Replaced power supply.
- Replaced monitor.
- [eeprom recovery](https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-eeprom/blob/master/releases.md) using Ubuntu imager utility to write SD card.
- eeprom recovery using Mac OS imager utility to write SD card.
- eeprom recovery via manual copy of eeprom recovery files to FAT SD card.
- Tried both HDMI output ports (neither shows physical damage.)
- Created new OS image.

What else can I try before I scrap this unit, and order a new one?

The rPi has been working just fine for a year or so, before this happened out of the blue.

plot-twist: It was a faulty HDMI cable. Apparently they can break down with normal use.

Comment: Try reflashing the OS. Do the HDMI ports look broken?

Comment: The eeprom will have nothing to do with this. It is more likely a faulty HDMI cable or faulty OS.

Comment: Also consider using it for something that does not need a screen (web server / vpn / file server etc) - shame to add to landfill if it can be repurposed...

Comment: Write it up as an answer: you were spot on: the HDMI cable is faulty. Thanks! I'm glad I replaced the cable (on your suggestion) before buying a new rPi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has a solution. in the comments it is noted, that the HDMI cable was broken. Replacing it with a new one solved the problem.